# How to set classes's property in callback in TypeScript?

Tags: jquery, typescript, callback, closures, ecmascript-5

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
class User {

    name: string;

    userService: UserService; //service which fetches data from server

    successCallback(response: any) {
          this.name = string; 
    }

    setUser() {     
       var xhr: JQueryXHR = this.userService.fetchUser(); //Returns JQueryXHR object
       xhr.then(this.successCallback);
    }
}
```

Now, when I call setUser method on an instance of the User class:

```
var user: User = new User();
user.setUser();
```

`this.name` in `successCallback` evaluates to undefined

How can I get hold of the attribute of the class in callback function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski The linked question refers to JavaScript but here I am asking specifically about TypeScript.

Comment: The options mentioned still apply. `.bind()` and bound arrow functions behave the same in both.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks! .bind() worked. I am on EcmaScript 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the method is evaluated in `window`s context.

Wrap the `xhr.then` call:

```
xhr.then(response => {
    this.successCallback(response);
});
```

The `=>` will make sure that `this` refers to the instance of this class.

Comment: I am on EcmaScript 5. This didn't work but xhr.then(successCallback.bind(this)); worked. => works in 6?

Comment: If you're compiling from TypeScript it should take care of everything for you.

Comment: I updated my answer, I didn't see `successCallback` has a parameter.